# Replace character in Powershell leaves Â

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to replace occurrences of '£' with 'GBP' within an XML file.  The line is read initially using this line of code:

```
$oldName = @(Select-Xml -Xml ([xml]$xml) -XPath "//fileName" | foreach {$_.Node.Innerxml} )
```

The replacement then happens using the following lines of code:

```
$newName = $oldName -replace('£', 'GBP')
(get-content $file) | foreach-object {$_ -replace [Regex]::Escape($oldName), $newName} | set-content $file
```

(I initially tried to perform an update to the XML element but had trouble so resorted to a basic -replace).

Although this does indeed find and replace a £ symbol with GBP, it also leaves in its place an Â (alt+0194) appearing as below:

```
'total of ÂGBP200.docx'
```

After this has happened, if I then manually edit the file and remove the Â and replace the GBP with the £ sign once again (back to 'total of £200.docx'), it will process correct the next time the script is run and there is no sign of the Â.

The encoding of the original XML file from which $oldName is read is UTF-7 and there is no encoding method specified for the 'set-content $file'.  I have tried specifying this as UTF-7 which adds alot of strange characters in place of the brackets and UTF-8 which again gives the Â.

I'd really appreciate a pointer and maybe if there's a more logical way to do this.

- I'm not sure if the Â is being read into $oldName or as a result of the -replace.

Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Why not use a normal string replacement: `[IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\path\file.xml', [Text.Encoding]::UTF7).Replace('£', 'GBP') | Out-File $file -encoding UTF8` ?

Comment: @wOxxOm I need to read the element content to use to rename the file also.  So there are 3 steps, i) read the element, 2) perform a replace in the XML file, 3) rename the file (to which the element refers).  If I do a normal string replacement I wouldn't have the element detail with the filename.